# Use two connections individually for a clob selection and updating statment, Is this fine?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

```
  private Clob getClob() throws exception{
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pStmt = null;
    try {
        conn = getConnection();
        pStmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT REFERENCE FROM TEST WHERE ID = ? FOR UPDATE OF REFERENCE");
        pStmt.setLong(1,1);
        ResultSet rset = pStmt.executeQuery();
        while (rset.next()) {
               Clob clob = rset.getClob(1);
               Writer writer = clob .getCharacterOutputStream();
               writer.write("string to be updated");
               writer.flush();
               writer.close();
               return clob;
        }
        return null;        
    } finally {
        cleanup(conn, pStmt, rset);
    }
 }

  public void updateClob() throws exception{
    Clob clob = getClob();

    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pStmt = null;
    try {
        conn = getConnection();
        pStmt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE TEST SET REFERENCE = ? WHERE ID = ?");
        pStmt.setLong(1,1);
        pStmt.setClob(2,clob );
        pStmt.executeUpdate();
    } finally {
        cleanup(conn, pStmt, null);
    }
 }
```

As you can see, I used two connections individually for opening and updating Clob. from method `getClob`:

Firstly I open a connection to read Clob locater and then release the connection, in next method `updateClob` I updated clob(it will open another connection),

My question is that, is this fine? no problem? because I saw a lot of example codes which used the same connection for selecting and updating statment.

Answer (score 0):

you can declare the `Connection` before calling the `getClob` and pass it as `parameter`, it will be initialized in `getClob` and then the same you can use in `updateClob`. Otherwise you can also do it by declare the `Connection` as a `Class` label variable. In this case you wont need to change much. But do not close the connection in `getClob`. please see the code below:

```
private Clob getClob(Connection conn) throws exception{
    PreparedStatement pStmt = null;
    try {
        conn = getConnection();
        pStmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT REFERENCE FROM TEST WHERE ID = ? FOR UPDATE OF REFERENCE");
        pStmt.setLong(1,1);
        ResultSet rset = pStmt.executeQuery();
        while (rset.next()) {
               Clob clob = rset.getClob(1);
               Writer writer = clob .getCharacterOutputStream();
               writer.write("string to be updated");
               writer.flush();
               writer.close();
               return clob;
        }
    return null;        
    } finally {
        pStmt.close();
    }
 }

  public void updateClob() throws exception{
    Connection conn = null;
    Clob clob = getClob(conn);
    PreparedStatement pStmt = null;
    try {
        pStmt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE TEST SET REFERENCE = ? WHERE ID = ?");
        pStmt.setLong(1,1);
        pStmt.setClob(2,clob );
        pStmt.executeUpdate();
    } finally {
        cleanup(conn, pStmt, null);
    }
 }
```

other method, class label :

```
private Connection conn;
private Clob getClob() throws exception{
    PreparedStatement pStmt = null;
    try {
        conn = getConnection();
        pStmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT REFERENCE FROM TEST WHERE ID = ? FOR UPDATE OF REFERENCE");
        pStmt.setLong(1,1);
        ResultSet rset = pStmt.executeQuery();
        while (rset.next()) {
               Clob clob = rset.getClob(1);
               Writer writer = clob .getCharacterOutputStream();
               writer.write("string to be updated");
               writer.flush();
               writer.close();
               return clob;
        }
    return null;        
    } finally {
        pStmt.close();
    }
 }

  public void updateClob() throws exception{        
    Clob clob = getClob();
    PreparedStatement pStmt = null;
    try {
        pStmt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE TEST SET REFERENCE = ? WHERE ID = ?");
        pStmt.setLong(1,1);
        pStmt.setClob(2,clob );
        pStmt.executeUpdate();
    } finally {
        cleanup(conn, pStmt, null);
    }
 }
```

Actually this is the better method then 1st one.

Comment: Thanks you. Yes, I see, but for reason I don't want change it if it can work properly. now I want know if I used two connections, will it have some problems?

Comment: all of them will work properly. so need not worry about functioning. but if you create and close the connection again and again. it will create performance issue.

Comment: and also it will create two object of connection so it will consume more memory also.

Comment: in your code snippet it will close connection in getClob, hence no connection available in updateClob

Comment: yeah but i have mentioned it in description that please don't close the connection in getClob method because I wanted the person to change accordingly. anyway i have updated it now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should avoid creating multiple connection as the database resources are limited and should be used with care.

Considering your usecase I would suggest not to create connection instead refactor your code in order to do better connection management.

For e.g since `updateClob` is a public method I assume it can be called from different code flow hence in the code snippet below connection is initialized in this method and the actual work is carried out by `private` methods who just uses the connection provided to them and dont create new one.

Also they dont close the connection passed to them, they leave the connection management to the caller, they just close whatever they are creating in this case `PreparedStatement`.

Code snippet:

```
private void getAndUpdateClob(Connection conn) throws Exception {
    Clob clob = getClob(conn);
    PreparedStatement pStmt = null;
    try {
        pStmt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE TEST SET REFERENCE = ? WHERE ID = ?");
        pStmt.setLong(1, 1);
        pStmt.setClob(2, clob);
        pStmt.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException sqlExp) {
        sqlExp.printStackTrace();
        throw sqlExp;
    } finally {
        if (pStmt != null) {
            pStmt.close();
        }
    }
}
private Clob getClob(Connection conn) throws Exception {
    PreparedStatement pStmt = null;
    try {
        pStmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT REFERENCE FROM TEST WHERE ID = ? FOR UPDATE OF REFERENCE");
        pStmt.setLong(1, 1);
        ResultSet rset = pStmt.executeQuery();
        while (rset.next()) {
            Clob clob = rset.getClob(1);
            Writer writer = clob.getCharacterOutputStream();
            writer.write("string to be updated");
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            return clob;
        }

    } catch (SQLException sqlExp) {
        sqlExp.printStackTrace();
        throw sqlExp;
    } finally {
        if (pStmt != null) {
            pStmt.close();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public void updateClob() throws Exception {
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = getConnection();
        getAndUpdateClob(conn);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing nothing in update it seems. You are getting the current clob in the database and then etting it back. Ideally it will be new clob isn't it in you update? Otherwise having separate connection for get and update (separate interface or method provided to say) is not abad thing.

Comment: I am using writer.write("string to be updated");writer.flush();writer.close();to write strings to clob, so the clob will be updated. but for performance consideration, I have updated codes to share the same connection between select and update statement.

Comment: I am not abig fan of passing connection across. Its more of an anti-pattern then pattern. Ideally you should get the connection in your method, do the work and commit or close. Thats not right by OOPs design philosophy.